# Plotly click events in pyscript

Tags: onclick, plotly, pyscript

My goal is to get the coordinates where a user clicked on a plotly plot. Plotly does support [click events](https://plotly.com/python/click-events/), but I am unable to get it working within [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/). Here is a MWE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
    <py-config>
        packages = ['plotly','numpy','pandas']
    </py-config>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    <py-script>
        import js, json, plotly
        import plotly.express as px

        fig = px.line(x=[1,2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3]) 
        # fig.data[0].on_click(select_params) # <-- does not work
        graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
        plot = js.Plotly.newPlot("chart1", js.JSON.parse(graphJSON))

        def select_params(trace, points, selector):
            print('Hello, World!')
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see:
The example you refer to isn't using Plotly express. So `import plotly.express as px` isn't importing what `import plotly.graph_objects as go` does in the example.

**However, I'm not quite seeing how to get the Plotly click to connect to the Pyscript.**

I was unable to see how to get the `go.FigureWidget()` working for now because it says it needs `ipywidgets>=7.0.0` but when I add ipywidgets to the list of packages to install it says there is no pure Python wheel then. Removing ipywidgets from that list restores the start-up working again.
The lack of `go.FigureWidget()` may be involved in it not working in my attempt.

Plotly includes drop-downs but [this recent example](https://towardsdatascience.com/pyscript-com-a-pyscript-ide-in-the-cloud-2b5bde6f0342) coded in the dropdown using Pyscript/s `py-change`, and so it doesn't point in a helpful direction since you want to be able to click in the Plotly plot.

This is closer than what you posted, **yet doesn't work** for showing 'Hello World if you click on a point in the plot.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
    <py-config>
        packages = ['plotly','numpy','pandas']
    </py-config>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="helloDiv"></div>
    <button id="my-button" py-onClick="display_hello()">Click me</button>
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    <py-script>
        import js, json, plotly
        #import plotly.express as px
        import plotly.graph_objects as go
        
        def select_params(trace, points, selector):
            display('Hello, World!', target="helloDiv")
        
        def display_hello():
            # this fails because we don't have any implicit target
            # from event handlers
            display('hello', target="helloDiv")

        #fig = px.line(x=[1,2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3]) 
        fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=[1,2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3]))
        fig.data[0].on_click(select_params)
        graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
        plot = js.Plotly.newPlot("chart1", js.JSON.parse(graphJSON))
 
    </py-script>

</body>
</html>
```